# Ldap: how to implement password history when user change their password

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

In Active Directory, how can I check so users can’t continue to use the same password over and over (when a user is changing password)?

Currently I am using following code to change password.

```
using (connection)
{
    connection.Bind();
    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(this._userDN, string.Format(Global.LDAPConstants.SEARCH_FILTER, this._accountFilter, userName), System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
    SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

    DirectoryAttributeModification modifyUserPassword = new DirectoryAttributeModification();
    modifyUserPassword.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;
    modifyUserPassword.Name = "unicodePwd";
    modifyUserPassword.Add(GetPasswordData(newPassword));

    ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(response.Entries[0].DistinguishedName, modifyUserPassword);
    DirectoryResponse dirResponse = connection.SendRequest(modifyRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Policy to enforce password history, so users cannot use the same password after changing.

Open your domain policy with policy editor, then go to Computer Configuration --> Policies --> Security Settings --> Password Policy. You will see "Enforce password policy", define a value.

Comment: Ok, Thanks to quickly response. will i be made some changes in the code?

Comment: You should get an exception after sending request because server will reject new password if it is used before and available in history.

Comment: Is this answer what you want?

Comment: Is this setting for ldap?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a setting for LDAP, but for AD. AD stores policy information and checks password history provides and LDAP retrieves an information from AD.

Ask your network administrator to set the Enforce password history option

[image]

Once set, user will not be able to set same password as N last passwords (max.24). The policy will be used by Windows (Ctrl+Alt+Del, change password) and all applications where you has a change password functionality. This is most secure and recommended way to implement password policy.

More details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875814.aspx

If you enter a password that violates the password history, you will get an exception

```
The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check 
the minimum password length, password complexity and password history 
requirements. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708C5)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked GPO setting and it is correct, but password history still not working with change password programmatically, I am using following code for change password which i have already mentioned above.

using (connection)

{

```
    connection.Bind();
    SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(this._userDN,string.Format(Global.LDAPConstants.SEARCH_FILTER, this._accountFilter, userName), System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
    SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

    DirectoryAttributeModification modifyUserPassword = new DirectoryAttributeModification();
    modifyUserPassword.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;
    modifyUserPassword.Name = "unicodePwd";
    modifyUserPassword.Add(GetPasswordData(newPassword));
    ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(response.Entries[0].DistinguishedName, modifyUserPassword);}
```

i have mentioned the image of our AD server setting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyVYP.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitdY.png

Comment: Did you try to refresh policy on the computer where password change is not working? 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739112(v=ws.10).aspx 

If policy is propagated then password history check should also work when changing the password using Ctrl+Alt+Del

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much , I changed the code of "change password" like this, now its working fine.

using (connection)

```
        {
            connection.Bind();
            SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(this._userDN, string.Format(Global.LDAPConstants.SEARCH_FILTER, this._accountFilter, userName), System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
            SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
            string path = "LDAP://" + this._domain + "/" + response.Entries[0].DistinguishedName;
            DirectoryEntry usr = new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, oldPassword);
            usr.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword });
            usr.CommitChanges();
        }
```